# In socket.io, listen [ socket.on(dynamic) ] dynamic emit event in angular 7

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io. can anyone please help me out to get a solution for this problem?  I am running angular 7.

**Server:**
Server Emit Event on Dynamic Created ID Like This:

```
io.emit('DynamicID1', data);
io.emit('DynamicID2', data);
io.emit('DynamicID3', data);
io.emit('DynamicID4', data);
io.emit('DynamicID4', data);
io.emit('DynamicID..N', data);
```

**Client:**
In Angular Side, Dynamic created ID Load use ajax. Like Below.

DynamicIDArray = HTTP.get('URL');

**Question Is How I Can Listen to Dynamic Created ID Change Event In Angular.**